# How can I get through the hospital basement with the woman alive?

Tags: silent-hill-2

I'm having a hard time playing on hard combat extra riddle in Silent Hill 2. In the hospital basement, the woman dies in three hits, even if I run all the way without bumping into a wall. Do I have to get a perfect run through the hallway? The difficulty spike jumped way too high here.

Comment: Now I gotta get this game. Is this the new one available on XBL download?

Comment: I have no idea. I play it on PC

Comment: It would help if you moved your edit to an answer: you are allowed to answer your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running away from the monster only applies to beginner and normal difficulty. On hard mode, running off wont be enough. The woman will get killed before you reach the elevator no matter what.

What you need to do is to shoot the monster until your gun is empty as soon as he shows up, reload on inventory, be careful not to hit the woman. And finally when you reach the red area of the hallway, shoot the monster through the fenced wall, the woman will catch up while the monster slows down, as soon as you empty your gun, you will now be able to run away safely to the elevator.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to simply run it on hard/hard and save your ammo. Push Maria to the first corner then run, run, run right to the end, don't stop to shoot the monster or wait on Maria.

--- A very important point--- you need to use the control stick on 2d mode to do this right otherwise James just can't turn fast enough. Get used to the 2d type control, memorise the turns in the hallway and you will breeze through this part without firing a single shot. Good luck.